# React-Native Imported Component not initializing its state on Parent state change

Tags: react-native

I am creating a Memory Card game on React-Native, I am using this repository for Flip Animation https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-flip.

On level 1 when I match all cards then I am setting state to change level and on Level 2 cards are still flipped, I want then to be on their initial state.

Level 1 before solving:
[Level 1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrWvg.png)

Level 2 after solving Level 1:
[Level 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qGw8.png)

What I want is on level 2, it should render imported CardFlip component drawing cards back face like it do initially (like in Level 1).

I am using react-native, not expo. Put this my code in App.js file and import card-flip repository and run-android this code with react-native.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View, Dimensions, Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import CardFlip from 'react-native-card-flip';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        page: true,
        level: 1,
        tries: 0,
      }
      this.width = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
      this.levels = {
        1:{cards:4,rowItems:2,tries:3,card_width:(this.width/2)-15},
        2:{cards:6,rowItems:2,tries:5,card_width:(this.width/2)-15},
        3:{cards:8,rowItems:2,tries:6,card_width:(this.width/2)-70},
        4:{cards:12,rowItems:3,tries:8,card_width:(this.width/3)-50},
        5:{cards:14,rowItems:3,tries:9,card_width:(this.width/3)-50},
        6:{cards:18,rowItems:3,tries:12,card_width:(this.width/3)-50},
        7:{cards:24,rowItems:4,tries:16,card_width:(this.width/4)-15},
        8:{cards:30,rowItems:5,tries:20,card_width:(this.width/5)-15},
        9:{cards:34,rowItems:5,tries:22,card_width:(this.width/5)-15},
        10:{cards:40,rowItems:5,tries:25,card_width:(this.width/5)-15}
      };
      this.dimens = {width: this.levels[this.state.level].card_width, height: this.levels[this.state.level].card_width};
  }

  go_next = () =>{
      this.setState({page: false, tries:0, level: 1});
  };
  go_home = () =>{
      this.setState({page: true});
  };

  tried = ()=>{ 
    this.setState({tries: this.state.tries+1});
  };
  level_up = ()=>{  
    console.log("level up: ", this.state.level+1);
    this.setState({level: this.state.level+1, tries: 0});
  };
  level_restart = ()=>{ 
    console.log("level restarted: ", this.state.level);  
    this.setState({level: this.state.level, tries: 0});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.page) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Cardy</Text>
            <Text>Color Memory Game for Kids</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.go_next}>
              <Image style={{marginBottom:30}} source={require("./assets/play.png")}></Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex:.1,alignItems: 'center',justifyContent:'flex-end',marginTop:20}}><Text style={styles.subheading}>Level {this.state.level}</Text><Text>Tries Remaining: {(this.levels[this.state.level].tries-this.state.tries)}</Text></View>
            
            <Cards dimens={this.dimens} cards={this.levels[this.state.level].cards} rowItems={this.levels[this.state.level].rowItems} tried={this.tried.bind(this)} level_up={this.level_up.bind(this)} level_restart={this.level_restart.bind(this)} level={this.state.level} tries={this.state.tries} total_tries={this.levels[this.state.level].tries} />

            <View style={{alignItems: 'center',flex:.1}}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.go_home}>
                <Text>&#8592; Go Home</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

class Cards extends Component<props> {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.color='';
      this.ckey='';
      this.tries=0;
      this.matched=0;
      this.level = this.props.level;
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if( this.level != nextProps.level || nextProps.tries==0 )
      return true;
    else return false;
  } 

  do_flip = (color, ckey)=>{
    if( this.color != '' ){ // second card flip
      this.props.tried();
      this.tries++;
      if( this.color == color ){  //card matched
        this.matched++;
        this["card"+ckey].flip();
        if( this.matched == this.props.cards/2 ){
          this.tries=0;
          this.matched=0;
          alert("Level completed successfully.");
          this.props.level_up(); 
        }
        else if( this.tries == this.props.total_tries ){
          alert("Sorry, Level failed, try again.");
          this.tries=0;
          this.matched=0;
          this.props.level_restart();
        }
      } else { // card not matched
        var pkey = this.ckey;
        this["card"+pkey].flip();
        if( this.tries == this.props.total_tries ){
          this.tries=0;
          this.matched=0;
          alert("Sorry, Level failed, try again.");
          this.props.level_restart();
        }
      }
      this.color='';
      this.ckey='';
    } else { // first card flip
      this["card"+ckey].flip();
      this.color=color;
      this.ckey=ckey;
    }
  };

  shuffleArray = (array) => {
      for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
      }
  }

  generate_cards = ()=>{
    const inner_cards = this.props.rowItems;
    const main_loops = Math.ceil(this.props.cards/inner_cards);
    const colors = ["blue","green","red","yellow","black","aliceblue","antiquewhite","aqua","aquamarine","azure","beige","bisque","blanchedalmond","blueviolet","brown","burlywood","cadetblue","chartreuse","chocolate","coral","cornflowerblue","cornsilk","crimson","cyan","darkblue","darkcyan","darkgoldenrod","darkgray","darkgreen","darkgrey","darkkhaki","darkmagenta","darkolivegreen","darkorange","darkorchid","darkred","darksalmon","darkseagreen","darkslateblue","darkslategrey","darkturquoise","darkviolet","deeppink","deepskyblue","dimgray","dimgrey","dodgerblue","firebrick","floralwhite","forestgreen","fuchsia","gainsboro","ghostwhite","gold","goldenrod","gray","greenyellow","grey","honeydew","hotpink","indianred","indigo","ivory","khaki","lavender","lavenderblush","lawngreen","lemonchiffon","lightblue","lightcoral","lightcyan","lightgoldenrodyellow","lightgray","lightgreen","lightgrey","lightpink","lightsalmon","lightseagreen","lightskyblue","lightslategrey","lightsteelblue","lightyellow","lime","limegreen","linen","magenta","maroon","mediumaquamarine","mediumblue","mediumorchid","mediumpurple","mediumseagreen","mediumslateblue","mediumspringgreen","mediumturquoise","mediumvioletred","midnightblue","mintcream","mistyrose","moccasin","navajowhite","navy","oldlace","olive","olivedrab","orange","orangered","orchid","palegoldenrod","palegreen","paleturquoise","palevioletred","papayawhip","peachpuff","peru","pink","plum","powderblue","purple","rebeccapurple","rosybrown","royalblue","saddlebrown","salmon","sandybrown","seagreen","seashell","sienna","silver","skyblue","slateblue","slategray","snow","springgreen","steelblue","tan","teal","thistle","tomato","turquoise","violet","wheat","yellowgreen"];
    var selected_colors = colors.slice(0, this.props.cards/2);
    selected_colors = selected_colors.concat(selected_colors);
    this.shuffleArray(selected_colors);
    var cd = 0;
    let row = [];
    let card = [];
    var list = selected_colors.map( (color, key)=> {
      if( cd == 0 ) { card = []; }
      card.push(
        <CardFlip style={this.props.dimens} key={key} ref={(card) => this["card"+key] = card}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={this.props.dimens} onPress={() => {this.do_flip(color,key); }} >
            <Image style={this.props.dimens} source={require("./assets/robot.png")}></Image>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0} style={[this.props.dimens]}>
            <View style={[{backgroundColor:color}, this.props.dimens]}></View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </CardFlip>
      );
      cd++;
      if( cd==inner_cards || key == selected_colors.length-1 ){
        cd=0;
        return  <View key={key+"a"} style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-evenly',alignItems: 'center'}}>{card}</View> 
      }
    }); 
    return list;
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{flex:.8}}>
      {this.generate_cards()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  heading:{
    fontSize: 40,
    color: 'green',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  subheading:{
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'green',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  boxContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor:'yellow'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You're initializing the state in the constructor, which only runs once at the time of component mounting. So when the state of parent component is changing, it is passing the props to the child, but the constructor of the child component is not running in that case, therefore the child component state is not behaving as you're expecting.

Something like this will work. Define `componentWillReceiveprops` in your child component, and setState if the newly received props are different than the previous one.

*I'm using a library lodash for comparing object, arrays and so on. I recommend you to us it*

**Example**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash';

class ChildComponent extends Component{
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ 
     if(!_.isEqual(this.props.something, nextProps.something) && Boolean(nextProps)){
        this.setState({something: nextProps.something})
     }
  }
  render(){
     return(

    )
  }
}
```

*Note: Try not to `setState` into the `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentDidUpdate` without a condition to ensure it won't lead you to infinite loop of setting state*

Comment: I am already using shouldComponentUpdate to check if this component should update or not, when I have updated to use componentWillReceiveProps then it is updating component always even though it is having check.


shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if( this.level != nextProps.level || nextProps.tries==0 )
      return true;
    else return false;
  }

Comment: you have written the wrong condition in if, it should be `this.props.level` not just `this.level`. Also, add the function in your code that I have written.

Comment: I have updated this code but still not working, I have updated this.level to this.state.level and have put it in state of this child component:
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if( this.state.ilevel != nextProps.level ){ 
      this.setState({ilevel: this.state.ilevel++});
    }
    else if ( nextProps.tries==0 ){
      this.setState({ilevel: this.state.ilevel});
    }
  }